# solaris test driver crashes

Tags: solaris, device-driver

In solaris I wrote a driver and it is crashing.. But my solaris kernel is also getting crashed because of it.  The driver is getting loaded every time the system resets and kernel is dumping core and reboots.. How to stop the loading of the crashing driver whenever the system reboots?

Comment: I'd say you'd get a better answer on superuser, as this is not programming specific.

Comment: What Solaris release and update are you using and on what architecture ?

Answer (score 1):

Too bad you aren't using Solaris 10 (or newer) which implement failsafe booting and has so many other improvements. Anyway, the simplest method to recover your system would be to boot on an OpenSolaris SPARC live CD like Milax ( http://genunix.org/distributions/dss/milax032sparc.iso ) or similar, mount your Solaris 9 root filesystem and remove your bogus driver from there.

When done, you might want to implement failsafe boot like explained here:

http://wikis.sun.com/display/BigAdmin/Back+port+Solaris+10+failsafe+feature+to+Solaris+9+and+below

Answer (score 0):

You have been following the recommended best practice of

> For safety and convenience, booting
>   with an alternate kernel is highly
>   encouraged.

Right? So unless you have an alternate kernel configured somewhere, and not been following the [best practices (development drivers go into /tmp)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19082-01/819-3159/fdlbq/index.html), you may have a serious problem there.

I guess you could net-boot from a second machine or CD as @jlliagre suggested, and then mount the local disks to remove the offending driver.